# Boot strap clock picker ( clockpicker is not a function)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner to bootstrap and jquery , when I tried using clockpicker package for bootstrap I came across this error.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clockpicker is not a function.

```
<html >
<head>
    <!-- Clockpicker and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clockpicker-gh-pages/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Time Slot</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid" >
            <form role="form" name="frm"  action ="timeslot" method="post" 
            onSubmit="return valid2()">

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" >Slot Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="slotname" class="form-control" placeholder="Time Slot name" >
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" >Time Slot</label>
                    <input type="text" name="slotname" class="form-control" placeholder="Time Slot name" >
             </div>
             <label for="name" >Time</label>
            <div class="input-group clockpicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:30px;"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker()
                .find('input').change(function(){
                    // TODO: time changed
                    console.log(this.value);
                });
            $('#demo-input').clockpicker({
                autoclose: true
            });

            if (something) {
                // Manual operations (after clockpicker is initialized).
                $('#demo-input').clockpicker('show') // Or hide, remove ...
                        .clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');
            }
            </script>


</body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="clockpicker-gh-pages/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="clockpicker-gh-pages/assets/js/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="clockpicker-gh-pages/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code you posted, you'll see that you are attempting to **run** clockpicker **before clockpicker is loaded**.

The simplest way to solve this problem is to use a jQuery `document ready` function, which causes your script to wait until the entire page is loaded before attempting to run:

```
// This line tells jQuery to wait until the whole page is loaded before running the code inside.
// This will solve your current problem, as well as many other potential problems.
jQuery(function($) {
        $('.clockpicker').clockpicker()
            .find('input').change(function(){
                // TODO: time changed
                console.log(this.value);
            });
        $('#demo-input').clockpicker({
            autoclose: true
        });

        if (something) {
            // Manual operations (after clockpicker is initialized).
            $('#demo-input').clockpicker('show') // Or hide, remove ...
                    .clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');
        }
// The line below "closes" the document ready function
});
```

Comment: Thanks again  @cale_b , I have a question in regards to the above code, in case i use a dynamic clockpicker  ( a clockpicker input opens upon add click button) how can i make my code work.

Comment: Post your code that opens the input and let me know and I will edit my answer - but I need to see your code to do so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685870/bootstrap-clock-picker-dynamic-input                 ........... have posted my code in the link provided in this post .. please help me with this ..   @cale_b